# Broken routes prevent access to launchpad

Tags: sitecore-client, launchpad

After reorganizing the solution and moving code files (controllers and views among other things) to other projects in order to implement the Helix principle I now seem to have broken something. I can still reach the Sitecore login page but when I do log in I get the Picture below rather than the launchpad.

I am running Sitecore 8.2 update 5.

Any advice on what might be broken and how to fix it is most welcome.

Thank you!

[image: ScreenShot of the error page]

Comment: Did you touch any Sitecore files? Can you check if in the subfolders in website/sitecore/shell/client has the launchpad resources?

Comment: ~\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\LaunchPad\Layouts\Renderings contains three .cshtml files. ~\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\LaunchPad contains three .js files, two .css files and one .less file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was that I had a corrupted global.asax file.

Once I restored that everything went back to normal.